# how to tell Git (msysgit on Windows) to use ssh and not pageant

Tags: git, ssh, github

I installed Git a while back on my Win7 machine and told it to use Putty for doing ssh. So now it expects Pageant to be running all the time in order to be able to connect to GitHub.

Today I installed a newer version of Git and told it to use OpenSSH, not Putty. But it keeps trying to authenticate by looking for Pageant.

My identity files are configured correctly, and if I do `ssh git@github.com` from my BASH prompt it succeeds. Still, the only way to the remote repo is if Pageant is running.

Where is this configured and how can I instruct msysgit to forget about putty/pageant?

Answer (score 9):

MsysGit should take [its ssh program from the `GIT_SSH` environment variable](http://markmail.org/message/lgtoktgoones55ut), so even if you did install a newer version, check that your current session include the right `GIT_SSH` value.

Comment: This envar is undefined. What value should it have?

Comment: @Assaf: as described in http://www.webos-internals.org/wiki/Applying_Patches, try a set `GIT_SSH=c:\path\to\openssh-ssh`