# fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly by connectiong to GitHub

Tags: authentication, github, ssh, connection

I've set up my local system for working with GitHub how descrided in the "[Generating SSH Keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys)" How-To.

The key files and the known_hosts have been created, the public key has been added to the GitHub account, and I get the message "Hi ***! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access."

[image]

But all my attempts to do something, what needs a connection to the server (EDIT: with writing access) -- git clone, git push etc. -- end with an error:

> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

EDIT:

I can clone, but only via HTTP (https://github.com/account/reponame.git) or Git Read-Only (git://github.com/account/reponame.git).

EDIT:

```
***@**** ~/.ssh
$ ssh-add -l
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

Although an ssh-agent daemon (`ssh-agent.exe`) is running.

Probably that is the problem.

Comment: That's strange, because the most probably thing causing this is a missing SSH key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works!

I've started the **Pageant** (PuTTY SSH authentication agent) and added my PuTTY private key `id_rsa.pkk` (exported with **PuTTYgen** (PuTTY Key Generator) from `id_rsa`) to it. Now I can write to my repos.

A small how-to for everyone, who has the same troubles I had:

0) Set up the local system for working with GitHub, how descrided in the "[Generating SSH Keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys)" How-To.

1) Open **PuTTYgen**, load/import the (OpenSSH) private key `id_rsa` and save it (button `Save private key`) as `id_rsa.pkk` (in the same folder, where `id_rsa` is saved, -- `~/.ssh`). You need this PuTTY variant of the key for PuTTY authentification with **Pageant** and (if you use it) TortoiseGit.

[image]

2a) Open **Pageant** (on my computer it's `C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\pageant.exe`) and add the PuTTY private key. Or just open the PuTTY private key file (`id_rsa.pkk`) with **Pageant**.

2b) For **TrtoiseGit** I had only to set the `SSH client` (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\ssh.exe`) in the global TrtoiseGit settings.

[image]

That's it.

> I've got it working, but I don't have a deep understanding of this
>   thema and cannot provide a low level explanation of the solution and
>   the causes of this problem (and e.g why it was working in some clients
>   and wasn't in some others). So feel free to edit/comment this post, if
>   you can explain all this better.

Answer (score 2):

The only instance where that error message pops up, while your public ssh key is correctly recorded by GitHub, is when

- you try to clone a repo with a wrong case or an improper ssh url.
  It should be:

```
git clone git@github.com:user/repo.git
```

- you try to clone a repo for which you don't have write access (public repo), or any access (private repo).
  From the GitHub page "[Which remote URL should I use?](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use)"

> To use these URLs, **you must have write access to a public repo or any access to a private repo**.
>   These URLs will not work with a public repo you do not have write access to.

- the private key is passphrase protected and your authentication agent doesn't run properly:

```
$ ssh-add -l
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

For the last case, consider "[How to run (git/ssh) authentication agent?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10077302/6309)" or "[ssh-add complains: Could not open a connection to your authentication agent](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48868)"

Comment: No, the mistake is somewhere else: It's my repo (so, I should have full acces to it) and I'm using the right SSH URL (copied from the GitHub website).

Comment: @automatix are you using a preivate key protected by a passphrase?

Comment: I've tried both -- with and without passphrase. The result is the same.

Comment: @automatix what is the value of your GIT_SSH environment variable ? (as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/5315762/6309). Does it reference plink.exe (as in http://gitolite.com/gitolite/putty.html)?

Comment: It reference `C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoisePlink.exe`

Comment: I've changed the GIT_SSH, so that it reference `C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe`. Now the output is a little bit different, but it seems to be caused by the same error: `Unable to open connection:
Network error: Cannot assign requested address
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

Comment: @automatix do you have the same issue in a `git-cmd` session ((instead of a git bash)?

Comment: I don't use `git-cmd`, but I have the same issue in `git bash` and (standrad Windows) cmd and also in TortoiseGit.

Comment: @automatix try and see if the issue persists with `git-cmd` (which is part of msysgit)

Comment: I've just treid ti with the "Git Shell" downloaded from [GitHub](http://windows.github.com/) (Windows Power Shell) -- and it has worked! Why is it working in the Git Shell and not working other tools???

Comment: Yes, you are right -- it's working in `git-cmd`. But why is it not working in the standard Windows `cmd` and other tools like `TortoiseGit` and `Git Bash`?

Comment: After I've tried it in several clients, I'd like to resume the current status: It's working in **Git Shell** (Windows Power Shell, downloaded from GitHub), **msysGit** (msys.bat), and **git-cmd** (that is part of msysGit). But it's still not working in **cmd** (the standard Windows command line), **Git Bash**, and with **TortoiseGit**.

Comment: It is also not working in the **GNOME Terminal** of my Debian VirtualMashine (but with another error: `ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: Name or service not known` \\ `fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`).

Comment: @automatix The Git Shell of "GitHub for Windows" is a Powershell one. The "git-cmd" of msysgit set a lot more environment variable than the git bash. In all cases, check the environment variables: they will make the difference.