# Gitolite clone fails

Tags: git, gitolite, tortoisegit

Whenever i try to clone any repository on my laptop i get this message:

```
Unable to open connection:
Host does not existfatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

however, when i use the same private key from my desktop i can clone without problems.

The clients are both TortoiseGit on Windows.

I thought i must have done something wrong, but i can't figure out why so i tried to copy the cloned git repository from my desktop to my laptop and now i can modify (push/pull/commit) to that repository from my laptop.

So somewhere the authentication works, yet i can't clone.

And worst of all, this suddenly happened for another member in our team too.

What i did:

1. Install TortoiseGit
2. Install msysgit
3. Setup ssh session in putty with the private key
4. do a git clone with that session (this fails)

Same thing as i did on the desktop, yet there it works, here on the laptop it fails.

But manually copying the repository and making changes does work, like it's only the git clone that gets denied.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the various debug tips mentioned in "[git push to remote repository “Could not read from remote repository”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118797/git-push-to-remote-repository-could-not-read-from-remote-repository/16119444#16119444)".

But first, check if the issue persists when using `openssh` instead of `plink.exe` for ssh communication (as mention in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15476497/6309)).

You can change the settings in TortoiseGit in `Settings>Network>SSH`:

[image: network]

Comment: well ehm, it can commit on that system with a manually copied repository, so i'm pretty sure it can communicate with the server.
And i did forget to say plink with the info command gives me a list of all repositories and recognizes my key

Comment: @StijnTallon sure, but would it work better with openssh instead of plink?

Comment: Would it? I have no clue, i'd rather see a solution that makes this computer work like the 8 others in the team then to make an exception for this one and install openssh instead of putty. 
I'll ask him to try, but it really isn't a solution, more of a workaround.

Comment: @StijnTallon I agree. Note that openssh comes with msysgit.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I installed tortoise then installed git.  I dont know anything about openssh.  I can get to the settings screen shown above, but dont know how to change it to openssh?

Comment: For Git itself, check your `GIT_SSH`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5315762/6309. The ssh packaged in your msysgit is an (old) openssh.